# How to calculate an average disregarding extreme results?

Tags: statistics

If I have a set of results like this one: {1, 3, 2, 5, 8, 1, 100, 150, 1, 3, 8, 3000}
And I want to calculate an average disregarding values that are really different from most of the result set {100, 150, 3000} is there any formula I can apply?

Thanks in advance (hope I haven't broken any rule from this SE) :)

Comment: [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outlier) might help.

Comment: If you don't get any answers here you could try [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: The median yields a possible solution to your problem.

Comment: Here's a specific post on Cross Validated that discusses several approaches to your problem: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16198/what-do-you-call-an-average-that-does-not-include-outliers